# Update the missed values based on previously filled in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the generic drug names based on the value in previous rows in the same table.

For instance:

```
Drug      Gen_Drug
Metsmall  Glipiz  
GLACE X   Glide
DREGO D   Diazo
Metsmall  Null 
Glace X   Null
```

Assume that the last two drug names were inserted recently.
I need to update the Gen_Drug column for these missing Drugs using the previous update.

Expected result:

```
Drug      Gen_Drug
Metsmall  Glipiz  
GLACE X   Glide
DREGO D   Diazo
Metsmall  Glipiz 
Glace X   Glide
```

Kindly suggest a code to update those names.

Comment: What column determines the order? And [edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: SQL tables have no ordering, so you need another column to define what order to look back in

Comment: Why did you change your database!?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify what you will use for ordering to determine which row(s) are the most "recent".

Assuming you have some sort of `date` or `identity` column to determin the most recent row you can do the following

```
with d as (
    select *,
      Row_Number() over(partition by Drug order by CreatedDateColumn desc) rn
    from t
    where Gen_Drug is not null
)
update t set t.Gen_Drug=d.Gen_Drug
from 
t join d on d.drug=t.drug
where t.Gen_Drug is null and d.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is exactly one identical gen for each drug, with this query you can update your table:

```
update yourTable tout
set tout.gen_drug = (select distinct tin.gen_drug 
                    from yourTable tin 
                    where tout.drug = tin.drug 
                    and tin.gen_drug is not null) 
where tout.gen_drug is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(gen_drug) over (partition by drug) as imputed_gen_drug
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set gen_drug = imputed_gen_drug
    where gen_drug is null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a while loop to accomplish this operation.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DrugTable where Gen_Drug IS NULL)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @drugName  NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 Drug FROM DrugTable WHERE Gen_Drug IS NULL)
    DECLARE @drugValue NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 Gen_Drug FROM DrugTable WHERE Gen_Drug IS NOT NULL and Drug = @drugName)
    UPDATE DrugTable SET Gen_Drug = @drugValue WHERE Drug = @drugName and Gen_Drug IS NULL

    PRINT('Updated ' + @drugName + ' with value: ' + @drugValue)
END
```